# How to use a fallback font with javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, text, fonts, fallback

I would like to know if I can detect if my actual font support all the characters of a string.

For exemple, we can see there that the unsupported characters are filled with Times New Roman, and the normal text is filled with the selected font :

[image]

But I would like to first put the whole text with the same font if one character is not supported, and too switch the font with Arial.

Any idea about how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

`ctx.font` uses the same syntax as [CSS's`font` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) (with the line-height param ignored), so you can specify the fallback fonts the same way as in CSS, i.e by adding multiple font-family values at the end:

```
ctx.font = "10px 'your font', Arial";
```

Comment: Nice, but how can I apply it to the whole text ? It's actually only putting the unsupported character in Arial, but let the supported one with the old font, and give a weird result

Answer (score 0):

To fallback all together, you could detect if any letters are using a fallback font by checking each letter's metrics against the fallback font, using [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText).

Note that ideally you should check each grapheme, rather than each code point. JavaScript's `for`-`of` loop iterates over the code points of a string, but there are libraries like [grapheme-splitter](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) to help with iterating over graphemes.

This solution might not be terribly performant, but for short text it should be fine, especially if you cache the result. Note that if you're caching it, you should ensure your font is loaded before caching, to avoid the need for cache invalidation when the font loads, and ideally before doing the test at all, since it *must* fall back in that case.

```js
/* const splitter = new GraphemeSplitter(); */
const font = "JinxedWizards";
const fallbackFont = "Arial, sans-serif";

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function usesFallback(text) {
    for (const grapheme of /*splitter.iterateGraphemes*/(text)) {
        ctx.font = "20px " + font + ", " + fallbackFont;
        const metrics = ctx.measureText(grapheme);
        ctx.font = "20px " + fallbackFont;
        const fallbackMetrics = ctx.measureText(grapheme);
        if (
            metrics.width === fallbackMetrics.width &&
            metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent === fallbackMetrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent &&
            metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent === fallbackMetrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent &&
            metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft === fallbackMetrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft &&
            metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight === fallbackMetrics.actualBoundingBoxRight
            /* fontBoundingBoxAscent seems to give different results somehow... don't ask me why!
            metrics.fontBoundingBoxAscent === fallbackMetrics.fontBoundingBoxAscent &&
            metrics.fontBoundingBoxDescent === fallbackMetrics.fontBoundingBoxDescent */
        ) {
            //console.log("fallback detected for", grapheme, metrics, fallbackMetrics);
            return true;
        } else {
            //console.log("differs for", grapheme, metrics, fallbackMetrics);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("usesFallback('testing')", usesFallback('testing'));
console.log("usesFallback('testing œ')", usesFallback('testing œ'));

// manually verify that we can display the font
document.body.append(canvas);
ctx.font = "20px " + font + ", " + fallbackFont;
ctx.fillText("testing œ", 50, 50);
```